# How do I geocode a Colombian address using Python 3 and geopy 1.21.0?

Tags: python, geocoding, street-address, geopy

I have been trying to geocode Colombian addresses but the resulting coordinates are not accurate at all. For example:

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
gc = Nominatim(user_agent="my_geocode_app")
gc.geocode("Calle 121 #48-60, Bogota")
```

The result:

```
Location(Calle 121, Bella Suiza, Usaquén, Distrito Capital, Bogotá, 1101, Colombia, (4.7000065, -74.0384207, 0.0))
```

That is not my location. According to Google Maps the correct coordinates would be (4.703340, -74.058408) But when I try with the addresses of places in any other country where I have lived the result is totally accurate. For example:

```
gc.geocode("Ibera 3851, Buenos Aires")
```

The result:

```
Location(3851, Iberá, Coghlan, Buenos Aires, Comuna 12, Ciudad Autónoma de Buenos Aires, C1430DHI, Argentina, (-34.5611637, -58.478657, 0.0))
```

That is the exact location where I used to live. So the problem is only with Colombian addresses. I tried French, German, Argentinian, Spaniard and USA addresses. All of them perfect.
Please let me know what is happening or how to geocode in the correct way a Colombian address because it looks like the format of the addresses of this country are not being read complete by geopy. Thanks in advance for your help.

These are some other examples of Colombian addresses all of them from Bogota the capital city. Just in case you wish to try them (They are very weird):

AVENIDA 72 # 54A-24

AVENIDA CALLE 17 # 78G-11

AVENIDA CARRERA 68 # 33-25 SUR

CARRERA 72 # 21-53

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a case of missing data in OpenStreetMap. That particular house number does not exist yet.

If the housenumber is mapped the search works fine. Example: Calle 122 # 21-43, Bogotá.